# Rectify smooth filler patches on sand and cement skimmed wall

Tags: painting, plaster, wood-filler

Someone did me a favour and sand and cemented​ by porch (long story). It had a few cracks afterwards and as I had lots of other things to filler I decided to filler all of the cracks "while i was at it". 
Yesterday I gave the wall a mist coat and now deeply regret my filler as the smooth patches on the scratchy wall are very visible.

What do you suggest I do to get a consistent finish without too much work? (Scratchy or smooth)

Thanks[image]

Comment: How much work is too much?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, I am desperate so open to some options?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the fun world of texture (intentional or not). This is why I dislike textured ceilings. Matching both the texture and color proves to be difficult, if not impossible.

While color is not an issue (this is new work), the texture is going to be a problem. There's no easy way to put a matching texture back on the smooth spots. What I would recommend is sanding it all smooth. Get a [rubbing brick](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Marshalltown-6-in-x-3-in-20-Grit-Concrete-Rub-Brick-840-HD/100318060) and work the wall until the texture change isn't noticeable anymore.

One other piece of advice: get a final opinion (after sanding) from someone not familiar with this. If a person seeing it for the first time can't notice, most people won't. Don't be too anal about the wall. Yes, you will know where you created smooth spots, but the average person doesn't scrutinize walls for flaws.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to sand a sand and cement wall smooth is it?

Comment: The idea would be to "level" the texture so it's not noticeable. You're right that a normal sanding system would not work here, hence the rubbing brick